# JavaScript notifications onclick event

Tags: javascript, webkit, notifications

as soon as Notification instantiates onclick function fires but I want prevent this event before actual click occures on notification

```
   var message = new Notification("RandomString");
   message.onclick(alert("Random Message"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var message = new Notification("RandomString");
message.onclick = function(){alert("Random Message")};
```

Comment: TypeError: message.onclick is not a function

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to break this down a little bit to make it more clear what your code is doing.

`message.onclick()` will invoke the `onclick` property of `message`, which is probably currently `null` and therefore can't be called as a function.

Inside of the `()` you have `alert("Random Message")`, which is going to be called right then. This means that the value of that function call will be passed in to the `onclick` function call as a parameter. `alert()` doesn't return anything, so the alert fires, then you're left with this:

```
message.onclick('undefined')
```

What you wanted to do was make `onclick` a function and have it call the `alert`.

```
message.onclick = function() {
  alert("Random Message")
};
```

Now you can fire that function by clicking the element it is attached to, or you can still fire it directly with `message.onclick()`.

The best practice now is to use `addEventListener` rather than `onclick`. `addEventListener` will allow you to register multiple events of the same type.

```
message.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("Random Message");
});
```

Another thing that newer programmers often don't realize is that you don't have to make the function while attaching it as the event listener. Here's an example using both methods:

```
function foo() {
  alert("Random Message");
}

message.onclick = foo;

message.addEventListener('click', foo);
```